# How can I make a search in vimscript let n and N look for more?

Tags: vimscript, search

I'm writing a script that does a search like so: `normal /needle^M`. This works like I want, except that I want to be able to use `n` or `N` to repeat the search.

In case it helps, here's the full function:

```
function! MakeChoices()
    let start = line('.')

    let choiceStartLine = search('^*choice', 'bW')

    let choiceEndLine = search('^\S.*', 'W') "End is first line that starts with non-whitespace

    "If above search fails, might be at bottom of buffer
    if choiceEndLine == 0
        let choiceEndLine = search('^$', 'W') "End is first empty line
    endif

    "Now go back up to the last *goto
    let choiceEndLine = search('*goto', 'bW')

    "Get the entire *choice block and put it in gotoBlock
    let gotoBlock = getline(choiceStartLine, choiceEndLine)

    "Make labelArray (contains all labels to goto)
    let labelArray = []

    for cur in gotoBlock
        if match(cur, '*goto') != -1
            "echo 'cur: '.cur
            let curParsed = matchlist(cur, '*goto \(\S\+\)')
            "echo curParsed
            if len(curParsed) > 1
                let curLabel = curParsed[1]
            else
                echo 'ERROR: Bad *goto ('.cur.')'
                return -1
            endif
            call add(labelArray, curLabel)  
        endif
    endfor

    "Make newline after choice block if needed
    if strlen(getline(choiceEndLine+1)) > 0
        echo 'big line: '.getline(choiceEndLine+1)
        call cursor(choiceEndLine, 1)
        put=''
    endif

    call cursor(choiceEndLine+1, 1)

    "Put the new label blocks
    let skippedLabels = ''
    let numNewLabels = 0
    for cur in labelArray
        if !search('*label '.cur, 'wn')
            let numNewLabels += 1
            put='*label '.cur
            put='[This option is yet to be written.]'
            put=''
        else
            let skippedLabels .= cur.' '
        endif
    endfor

    "Remove trailing blank lines (Up to a point)
    let nextlines = getline(line('.')+1, line('.')+3)
    if len(nextlines) == 3
        if nextlines[0] == '' && nextlines[1] == '' && nextlines[2] == ''
            normal "_3dd
        elseif nextlines[0] == '' && nextlines[1] == ''
            normal "_2dd
        elseif nextlines[0] == ''
            normal "_dd
        endif
    endif

    "Move to first label's text (use ctrl-v ctrl-m to input the <CR> at
    "end)
    if numNewLabels != 0
        call cursor(choiceEndLine, 1)
        normal /\[This option is yet to be written.\]
    endif

    "Print status message
    if len(skippedLabels) > 0
        echo 'Skipped: '.skippedLabels
    else
        echo 'New labels created: '.numNewLabels
    endif

endfunction
```

The line in question is near the end, and you can probably just ignore the rest of the code. Basically, this function parses some code (in a language called ChoiceScript) and outputs a set of stock templates based on that code, then jumps (via the vim search command in question) to the first stock template.

For example, let's say I begin with this ChoiceScript code:

```
*choice
    #Option A
        *goto optionA
    #Option B
        *goto optionB
```

Then, after running the function, the file becomes:

```
*choice
    #Option A
        *goto optionA
    #Option B
        *goto optionB

*label optionA
[This option is yet to be written.]

*label optionB
[This option is yet to be written.]
```

The cursor will be on the first "[This option is yet to be written.]", and I want to be able to hit `n` to jump to the second if that's the option I want to work on first.

Comment: I used it in a function and had no problem using `n` or `N` to repeat the search. Do you have an interfering plugin? Try with `vim -Nu NONE`, manually defining the function or action.

Comment: @muru, thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, and it still didn't work. Hitting `n` repeated a search earlier in the `/` history, but if I typed `/` and then hit the up arrow, the latest, function-called search appeared. I hit enter, it worked, and then `n` worked, so this is very odd. Perhaps it's a bug in vim itself? My version is 7.4.692.

Comment: I attempted a workaround by putting `normal /<Up>^MN` after the `normal /needle^M` line in my function, but the `<Up>` didn't work. Is it possible somehow or is there some other workaround?

Comment: You can set the regexp used for `n` by assigning it to the `/` register: `let @/="needle"`.  You don't even need to run a search first for that to work.

Comment: Please add your full function and possibly more background to your question. What you ask is the normal behavior so there must be something else.

Comment: @romainl, I have done as you requested. I hope it helps.

Comment: @lcd047, your suggestion does indeed produce the proper behavior, but why isn't my function working without it?

Comment: Your function doesn't work because `n` and `N` use the `/` register, and `search()` doesn't update the `/` register.

Comment: `search()` is used elsewhere, but the search for which I want to use `n` and `N` is `normal /\[This option is yet to be written.\]`.

Answer (score 7):

From [`:help function-search-undo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function%2dsearch%2dundo)

> The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
>   will not be changed by the function.  This also
>   implies that the effect of `:nohlsearch` is undone
>   when the function returns.

This is a bit of a "hidden" feature... Another "hidden" feature is that assigning
directly to `@/` overrides this behaviour:

```
fun! X()
    /Hello
    let @/ = 'Hello'
endfun
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on `search()`. However, setting @/ is what I actually wanted to do by using `normal` instead.

Comment: @Gantron Right; updated the answer.

Comment: Good to know. However, if vim works this way, why does the search wind up in the search history?

Answer (score 3):

One neat trick is to use `feedkeys("/pattern\<CR>")`.
This works differently than using :normal because the keys being fed into vim gets evaluated after the function returns so the problem with search direction and search pattern being reset goes away. ;-)
This actually lets you control both search pattern AND search direction from your function. I have found no other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are doing that inside a function, which will reset the `/` after it completes. From `:help quote_/`:

```
Note that the valued is restored when returning from a function |function-search-undo|.
```

To overcome this behavior you need to manually update the *Last search pattern register* by adding the following command to the function along with the search `/needle` call:

```
let @/='needle'
```

Note: using `needle` only as an example search.

Comment: Forcing its storage by setting `@/` worked. Thanks! However, what do you mean `/` resets after the function completes? The search in question shows up when I hit `/` followed by the up arrow when back in normal mode after running my function, so doesn't that mean it didn't reset?