# Searching with vimscript function

Tags: vimscript, search

I want to create a custom search in vimscript, using this line for searching:

```
:execute "normal gg/[A-Z]\\+*.:\<cr>"
```

it will tell me (correctly) that it searched for the pattern:

```
/[A-Z]\+3a.*:
```

but it will not highlight/search for anything. Pressing 'n' will continue the last search from before. Executing the exact same command directly in vim has the desired effect.

Can somebody explain to me why this doesn't work and how to do it correctly?

Comment: As i stated inthe question, the command works fine if executed normally and not withing a script meaning i have set hlsearch.

Comment: See `:h function-search-undo`

Comment: `:execute` is useless, here: you only need `:normal ...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a search in vimscript let n and N look for more?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/how-can-i-make-a-search-in-vimscript-let-n-and-n-look-for-more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is stated in `:h function-search-undo`. I worked around this by letting my function return the line and mapping it like this:

```
map <KEY> :call function()<CR>
```

Credits to VanLaser.

Comment: It's `:call Myfunction()<CR>`.